# VB.NET/Access DataGridView not displaying table contents

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I'm attempting to display an Access Database table in a DataGridView on the most simple form you could make.  However, when I start the application I don't see any of the table data.   See below.

I'm happy to update with any additional information needed.

VB:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MOKANDataSet.SalaryHistory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SalaryHistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MOKANDataSet.SalaryHistory)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the application at runtime.

[image: VB.NET Form sans Access database information.]

Overview of project in Visual Studio

[image: Overview of project in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious and went directly to the executable in the bin folder.   Upon execution, I got "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.   I'm using Win 7 64 Bit, but the Microsoft Office suite I have is 32-bit.   I got the 32-bit AccessDatabase Engine referenced [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cfb9efe8-4de2-40b6-b817-553c91b9f9c6/the-microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=csharpgeneral)